# $.ajax POST opens an new window on IE8

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, post, internet-explorer-8

I'm getting this weird response from IE8 (only IE8) when submitting customer information via an ajax POST.

The action is executed correctly, the customer is created on the CRM and all subsequent actions are executed, but also the window re-opens, that is a new window with the top URL pops up...

I can't pinpoint why this is happening. I stripped the code to include only the post call without success.

Working code is below, I just took the company ID for security reasons.

Any ideas?

- Javascript

  ```
  $(document).ready(function () {
      $('button').click(function () {
          postNsData();
      });
  });

  function postNsData() {
      var nsurl = 'https://forms.netsuite.com/app/site/crm/externalleadpage.nl';
      var datamin = {
          compid: xxxxxx, //Company ID -- it's a number.
          formid: 503,
          h: '1e705f3aa4570f197aef',
          leadsource: 8020,
          subsidiary: 2,
          email: 'email@gmail.com',
          firstname: 'John',
          lastname: 'Doe',
          phone: '1800902011',
      };

      $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: 'repost.php',
          data: 'url=' + nsurl + '&' + data,
          success: function (text, textStatus, jqXHR) {
              if (textStatus == 'success') {}
          }
      });
  }
  ```
- PHP Code -- repost.php

  ```
  <? php
  //set POST variables
  $url = $_POST['url'];
  unset($_POST['url']);
  $fields_string = "";
  //url-ify the data for the POST
  foreach($_POST as $key = > $value) {
      $fields_string. = $key.'='.$value.'&';
  }

  $fields_string = rtrim($fields_string, '&');
  //open connection    
  $ch = curl_init();
  //set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($_POST));
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
  //execute post

  $result = curl_exec($ch);

  //close connection

  curl_close($ch);

  ?>
  ```

Comment: Don't know why they made IE..:P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should update you javascript to look like this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('button').click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        postNsData();
    });
});
```

What it may be happening is that IE correctly does assume that you want to execute the link AND execute the javascript.